# ios keyboard not showing in Settings

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, keyboard, ios8

After following the steps in [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html), the custom keyboard section is not shown in the Settings.

One thing that I noticed, is that when setting up the project the "Embed in Application" drop down was set to None and had no other options. Also the directions said to add a Bundle display name row in my plist, but that was already there and had the project/keyboard name there.

I can run the keyboard project and it does ask for me to choose an application (I picked Safari). Then I expected to be able to go to the settings and enable my keyboard, but it is not there.

[image: settings image]

Comment: I encounter the same problem. Do you find any solution yet? Thanks

Answer (score 25):

Make sure the Keyboard Extension Target->General->Deployment Target is not newer than your device's current OS version.

Comment: searched about an hour and almost gave up and then this, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: This is still useful. When adding the extension, it will set the extension deployment target to the last iOS version, not the main app’s one.

Comment: Helped me after wasting an hour.

Answer (score 6):

You can try the following option, as it helped in my case:

1. Select your main app target.
2. Select "Build Phases"
3. Expand "Embed App Extensions"
4. Make sure that checkbox for "Copy only when installing" is unchecked
5. Run your app and check again Settings

[image]

Comment: This is a lifesaver. None of my extensions showed up and I spent days looking for the cause. You're my hero.

Comment: This is very helpful!!

Comment: 9 years later, still helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

it's just simply solved by adding settings bundle in application 
[image: add empty settings bundle]

Answer (score 3):

For me, the only thing that worked was **restarting the phone**.

I could run the main app target and also debug the keyboard extension in another app, however it wouldn't show up in the list at `Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> Keyboards -> Add New Keyboard...`.

As soon as the phone was restarted, the keyboard extension showed up in the list straight away.

My guess is that adding and removing the keyboard many times has the potential to confuse iOS and result in it thinking that the keyboard had already been added (hence why it doesn't show up in the list).

Answer (score -1):

This link may help

http://verisage.us/en/blog/2014/07/17/ios-8-custom-keyboard-swift-tutorial/

In short, you need an dummy app to deploy the keyboard.

---

Search "**To run the custom keyboard and attach the Xcode debugger**" in the following link.
You will find how to attach the process to debugger.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW7